# Why my logo doesn't fade out after 3 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I have following script:

```
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -loop 1 -i C:\xv\logo.png -i C:\xv\logo2.png -filter_complex "[2:v]fade=out:st=3:d=1[w0];[0:v]scale=1920:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:shortest=1,scale=iw:ih,format=yuv420p[tmp1];[tmp1][w0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5,scale=iw:ih,format=yuv420p" -codec:a copy  "C:\xv\%~nx1"
```

As you can see my video adding 2 logos on the video. And first logo works how i want so for whole video is displayed. But second logo(logo2.png) is not fading after 3 seconds. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Change command to

`ffmpeg -i "%~1" -loop 1 -i C:\xv\logo.png -loop 1 -i C:\xv\logo2.png ...`

An image is a video stream consisting of one frame, so there's no frames to apply the fade unless looped. Enable shortest for 2nd overlay as well.